# How to pass Resolve callback into a Promise when using async-await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, es6-promise

Let's say I have a function that returns a `Promise`:

```
let logData = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // doing some stuff
        resolve('data');
    });
};
```

And let's say I have a callback function for `resolve` callback:

```
let resolveCallback = function (data) {
    console.log(`doing some stuff with ${data}`);
};
```

When I'm simply using promises without `async-await` I can pass this callback into a promise very easily, like so:

```
logData().then(resolveCallback);
```

In this example when my promise is executing it will reach `resolve('data');` line and `resolveCallback` will be executed because `resolve = resolveCallback`

Now when I'm using `async-await` approach, is it possible to pass `resolveCallback` into the promise, somehow?

```
async function logDataAsync() {
    // IS THERE NO WAY TO PASS resolveCallback as resolve PARAMETER HERE???
    await logData();
}
```

Comment: If you're using promises, don't  mix with plain callbacks.  The caller should use the promise returned from `logDataAsync()` as in `logDataAsync().then(resolveCallback)`.  There's no need to invent a different callback mechanism.  Use the one already built into promises.

Comment: What problem  are you really trying to solve here?  Wrapping synchronous code in a promise does not make it asynchronous.  I suspect you don't really understand the proper way to do whatever you're trying to do so you're trying to force promises to do something they don't actually  do.  But, since you haven't described the REAL problem you're trying to solve, we can't really help you with that yet.  FYI, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you describe problems with your solution rather than describe the actual problem.

Comment: FYI, `resolve !== resolveCallback` so you have that part wrong.  `resolve()` is its own function.  Calling it causes `resolveCallback()` and any other `.then()` handlers to get called.  `.then()` registers a callback to get called when the promise resolves at some future time.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks, I am not solving any problems, it's just a curiosity question. I want to get to the nuts and bolts of promises.

Comment: @jfriend00 If you are saying that `resolve !== resolveCallback` Can you please explain how `resolve` really works? because I thought that `resolve` is just a callback you have to pass to the promise (and that's what most of the tutorials on the web say) so when I do `.then(resolveCallback)` it pretty much means I replace  resolve('data') with resolveCallback('data') which seemingly is not the case.

Comment: When you call `.then()` is adds a callback to an internal array of callbacks.  When `resolve()` gets called, that causes all the callbacks in the array to get called (after a short delay for the stack to unwind). There can be lots of different callbacks in that internal array because `.then()` can be called more than once on the same promise, each time registering another callback.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you! And when I do `let data = await logData();` how does it know that `data` should be returned? I assume `resolve('data')` has some kind of return statement, like `return data` inside of it, so that, when `await` is called it knows how to retrieve the result from a promise?

Comment: `logData()` returns a promise.  `await logData()` returns the resolved value of the promise.  It's how `await` works.  When you await a promise in Javascript, it suspends execution of the function until that promise resolves or rejects.  If it resolves, it assigns the resolved value to your `data` variable and then continues execution of the program.  It's like doing `logData().then(data => { /* your code here */})`.

Comment: I should mention that stackoverflow comments aren't really meant for a steady stream of new questions.  They're for comments about the question you already wrote.  It's probably best to do some reading about `await` and promises in general and then ask a new question if you get stuck on some other concepts.  There are thousands of articles on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function logDataAsync() {
// IS THERE NO WAY TO PASS resolveCallback as resolve PARAMETER HERE???
    const res = await logData();
    resolveCallback(res);
}
```

Same as

```
logData().then(resolveCallback)
```

Comment: This is not a recommended design pattern. The caller of `logDataAsync()` should use the promise it returns to monitor its completion.